# Binding datatable to a custom GridView control generates null reference exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I am having an issue binding a datatable to a custom gridview control. The issue I am experiencing is a nullreference exception when I am databinding to the control.

When the datasource is a datatable populated by SqlDataAdapter, the gridview binds with no issue. Here is the code that works fine for me:

```
    public override void Load(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
        {
            using (dbCheckpointWarehouseDataContext thisDataContext = new dbCheckpointWarehouseDataContext())
            {
                var qryItemCount = [LINQ QUERY THAT WORKS FINE.]

                using (SqlCommand cmd = thisDataContext.GetCommand(qryItemCount) as SqlCommand)
                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        adapter.Fill(dt);
                    }
                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {

                        CustomGridView cgvResults = new CustomGridView();
                        cgvResults.AddBoundField("DistrictManagerName", "District Manager", "");
                        cgvResults.AddBoundField("newMetric", "newMetric", "");
                        cgvResults.DataSource = dt;
                        cgvResults.DataBind();

                        m_ReportHTMLString = Utilities.RenderHTMLStringOfControl(cgvResults);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

If I try to load the same custom control with a strongly typed datatable, I get the null reference exception.  There are three lines commented out where I bind the datatable to a stock gridview control.  That also works.  I only experience the issue when I use a strongly typed datatable with the custom gridview. The exception is generated at the DataBind() method.  In debugging mode I have validated that the datatable is not empty, and there are no exceptions when I set the DataSource property. Here is the code that generates the null reference:

```
    public override void Load(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
        {

            dt.Columns.Add("DistrictManagerName", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("newMetric", typeof(Int32));

            DataRow row;

            using (dbCheckpointWarehouseDataContext thisDataContext = new dbCheckpointWarehouseDataContext())
            {
                var qryItemCount = [LINQ QUERY THAT WORKS FINE.]
                                  .AsEnumerable()
                                  .Select([SELECT STATEMENT THAT WORKS FINE])


                foreach (var rowtrans in qryTest)
                {
                    row = dt.NewRow();
                    row["DistrictManagerName"] = rowtrans.DistrictManagerName;
                    row["newMetric"] = Convert.ToInt32(rowtrans.newMetric);
                    dt.Rows.Add(row);
                }

                string total = dt.Compute("Sum(newMetric)", "").ToString();

                row = dt.NewRow();
                row["DistrictManagerName"] = "Total";
                row["newMetric"] = String.Format("{0:#,0}", total);
                dt.Rows.Add(row);
                dt.AcceptChanges();

                CustomGridView cgvResults = new CustomGridView();
                cgvResults.AddBoundField("", "District Manager", "");
                cgvResults.AddBoundField("", "Total", "");
                cgvResults.DataSource = dt;
                cgvResults.DataBind();

                //GridView cgvResults = new GridView();
                //cgvResults.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
                //cgvResults.DataBind();

                m_ReportHTMLString = Utilities.RenderHTMLStringOfControl(cgvResults);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the code for the custom gridview control:

```
    public CustomGridView() : base()
    {
        AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        AllowPaging = true;
        AllowSorting = true;
        PageSize = 25;
        GridLines = GridLines.Vertical;
        CssClass = "gridView";
        HeaderStyle.CssClass = "gridViewHeader";
        RowStyle.CssClass = "gridViewRow";
        AlternatingRowStyle.CssClass = "gridViewAlternatingRow";
        PagerStyle.CssClass = "gridViewPager";
        CellPadding = 3;
    }

    public void AddBoundField(string dataField, string headerText, string sortExpression)
    {
        BoundField bf = new BoundField();

        if (dataField != "")
        {
            bf.DataField = dataField;
        }

        if (headerText != "")
        {
            bf.HeaderText = headerText;
        }

        if (sortExpression != "")
        {
            bf.SortExpression = sortExpression;
        }

        Columns.Add(bf);
    }
```

Thank you for any help that you can offer.

Comment: As an aside, it is not necessary to use the `using`-statement for a `DataTable` since it just implements `IDisposable` for it's drag&drop capalities on the dataset designer. The same applies to a `DataSet`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  That is a holdout from my VBA days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.  I changed the setting:

```
AllowPaging = true
```

to

```
AllowPaging = false
```

My custom control now works as I expect it to.

I am hoping someone may be able to explain why this setting caused a NullReference exception on strongly typed datasets.